# How do i change discord.py version?

Tags: python, pip, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to install discord.py, but when I do it return this error:

`ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. discord-ext-slash 0.9.2 requires discord.py<1.8,>=1.5, but you have discord-py 2.3.1 which is incompatible.`

Using:
`pip install discord.py`

Answer (score 0):

Pip tries to change the versions of packages that depend on a package that you change the version of (through its "dependancy resolver"), but one of your packages does not have a version that works with a new version of discord.py.

You can either uninstall or **update `discord-ext-slash`** (run `pip uninstall discord-ext-slash` or `pip install --upgrade discord-ext-slash`), or **add the `--no-dependencies` flag to your pip command**. Keep in mind that this may cause errors in `discord-ext-slash`.

If you still want to use `discord-ext-slash`, but cant update it, then you must run `pip install discord.py==1.7.3` (the newest version < 1.8). This will install an old version of discord.py though, and is probably not a good idea, as there have been many changes to discord's API since 2021 when that version was released.

Answer (score -4):

The error message indicates a dependency conflict between the discord-ext-slash package and the discord-py package. The discord-ext-slash package requires a version of discord.py that is less than 1.8 but greater than or equal to 1.5. However, you have a different version of discord.py installed (version 2.3.1) that is not compatible with the requirements of discord-ext-slash.

To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

Update the discord-ext-slash package: Check if there is a newer version of the discord-ext-slash package available that is compatible with discord.py version 2.3.1. You can try running the following command to update the package:

```
pip install --upgrade discord-ext-slash
```

Downgrade the discord-py package: If you specifically need to use discord.py version 1.5.x, you can downgrade the discord-py package to a compatible version. Run the following command to install a specific version of discord.py:

```
pip install discord.py==1.7.3
```

Note: Replace 1.7.3 with the appropriate version that satisfies the requirements of discord-ext-slash.

Remove the conflicting package: If you don't actually need the discord-ext-slash package or can work without it, you can uninstall it and then install discord.py. Use the following commands:

```
pip uninstall discord-ext-slash
pip install discord.py
```

This will remove the conflicting package and install discord.py without any dependency conflicts.

Consider choosing the option that best suits your requirements and allows you to resolve the dependency conflict between discord-ext-slash and discord.py.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT